# Wordpress upload file not working on open even though link is correct

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, permissions

I've got a strange problem with Wordpress. I've added a PDF via the upload media button.

When I click to view the file on the page it takes me to a 404 error page, however I know the link is correct so I click enter in the URL bar again and the file will load.

I tried changing the wp-content directory permissions to 777 but no dice either.

What could be causing this issue? Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles across this problem it was with the htaccess file. I removed the Hotlinking part that WP had added and then it started to work again. I'm still not sure why it was interfering with it though.